# Associating two tables in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a new to rails, and as a sample project i want to make a web page where i can show all the states list, all Contries list, and all cities list. i have generated a model Contry and i am successfully  showing all the contries to user, and perform operations like (Edit, show ,Delete). now i want to add Model State and then show all the States and corresponding Contry. i have given a reference to Contry model from my State model. but i don't know the syntax to show the join data of State and Contry model. here is what i am trying in my State controllers create method. any help will be appreciated.

```
def create
  @contry = Contry.find(params[:contry_id])
  @state = @contry.states.create(state_params)
  redirect_to state_path(@state)
end

private
def state_params
  params.require(:state).permit(:name) 
end
```

Here is my State models Schema.

```
class CreateStates < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
   create_table :states do |t|
    t.string :name
    t.references :contry, index: true, foreign_key: true

    t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
 end
```

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html - An awesome source to start with.

Answer (score 0):

models:
Country.rb

```
has_many :states
```

State.rb

```
belongs_to :country
```

and now:

```
@country = Country.includes(:states).find(params[:id])
@states = @country.states
```

or

```
@state = State.includes(:country).find(params[:id])
@country = @state.country
```